# Moving elements on a layout controlled programmatically

Tags: layout, android-layout, android

My goal is to create something like the arrow from car that indicates the speed of the car. My problem is that I do not know what is the best practice for moving the green arrow. I have an image arrow.png and I guess I need to manipulate with the place that the picture is shown and with the rotation of the image.

Can someone point to me some guidelines ?
My basic idea is to have a relative layout for the background and to have one image view that will change the position, but the part changing position is little unclear to me. And I do not think that is good idea to play with layout params and margins...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would probably extend ImageView then override your onDraw method and use canvas.rotate() to rotate the arrow depending on your app state.